# Cannot find String.format in Kotlin Multiplatform shared module

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I find this weird. I am trying to use `String.format` in my `shared` module code in a Kotlin Multiplatform setup. It cannot find the `format` function and does not autocomplete in Android Studio. But it is working fine in the `androidMain` module.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, `format` needs platform localization info. KMP does not directly support localization. That function is available for the JVM (or Android) code.
You'll need to do some kind of expect/actual, or find some kind of library that does this, although I don't know of any off-hand.